# Twig syntax error while creating a form with {{ form_widget(form) }} in Silex micro-framework (symfony-forms)

Tags: twig, symfony-forms, silex, twig-extension

I am playing with Silex microframework. First I have installed Twig extensions for Twig with composer:

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

I added this configuration to my front controller (index.php):

```
// CONFIG 
    // turn on debug in Silex microframework
    $app['debug'] = true;

    // set default twig file location
    // turn on debuging for Twig extension in Silex
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
            'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../templets',
            'twig.options' => array('debug' => true),
        )
    );
    $app['twig']->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());

   // Symfony2 extension for building and validating forms in Silex
   $app->register(new Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider());
   $app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());
   $app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider());
```

Everything sims to work as expected but when creating a form with a widget

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

I get this error from Twig debuger:

> 1/1 Twig_Error_Syntax in ExpressionParser.php line 573: Unknown
>   "form_widget" function in "post.twig" at line 35.

If I comment out this line of code:

```
// $app['twig']->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

in my front controler, everything works fine and the form is renderd with no problems.

Is this the issue with the twig debug extension ? Perhaps some incompatibilyty ?.

I do not need to use widget_form to render my forms in twig. I use it just for quick testing purpose, before i get to write the rendering in twig properly - but still I don't see the reason why twig would throw an error for this.

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.3",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "~2.3",
        "symfony/console": "~2.3",
        "symfony/config": "~2.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~2.3",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~2.3",
        "symfony/filesystem": "~2.3",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.3",
        "symfony/form": "~2.3",
        "symfony/locale": "~2.3",
        "symfony/process": "~2.3",
        "symfony/security": "~2.3",
        "symfony/serializer": "~2.3",
        "symfony/translation": "~2.3",
        "symfony/validator": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.3",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": ">=2.2.0,<2.4.0-dev",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "5.*",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but can you make sure that you have the twig-bridge installed?

Comment: I have installed "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `symfony/twig-bridge` in integrated your project.

Comment: Thx for sugestion but i have "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3", already installed

Answer (score 0):

I guess this example sorted the issue for me (new way to include extension in Pimple):

```
// CONFIG 

    // turn on debug in silex
    $app['debug'] = true;

    // register twig and enable debug
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
            'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../templets',
            'twig.options' => array('debug' => true),
        )
    );

        // add twig debug extension in Pimpel (the new way)
        $app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
            $twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());
            return $twig;
        }));
```